# perl using open3 to write to STDIN and capture STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: windows, perl, stream

I'm using a Windows x64 machine and am trying to capture the STDOUT and STDERR streams from a command. I also have to write to the command's STDIN. I'm trying to use perl's IPC::Open3 for this, with no luck. I'm using the script posted [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?abspart=1;displaytype=displaycode;node_id=150775;part=1) and the command as this script [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?abspart=1;displaytype=displaycode;node_id=150748;part=3). I of course replaced the $cmd variable with "perl test.pl" for Windows.

It's supposed to print 'StdOut!' and 'StdErr!', along with the pid, but I only get the PID. I don't know if it is because of my operating system, or because the thread is 10 years old (no biggie, Perl 5 is almost 18, right?). Another monk posted [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=151886) script to fix any problems in the other one, but on my computer it never exits.

Can anyone give me a working example of using open3 to start a command in perl, write to its STDIN, and capture both its STDERR and its STDOUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` only works for sockets in Windows; it doesn't work on pipes. You could create sockets instead and pass those to `open3` instead of letting it create pipes for you (as seen [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=811650)), but I suggest that you use a higher-level module such as [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) instead. `open3` is a rather low-level function.